# Storybook shows [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <my-button> and does not mount Typescript component

Tags: typescript, vue.js, nuxt.js, storybook

I'm trying to make a project using Nuxt, Typescript, and Storybook. I have a one component, which is a simple button. However, when I run Storybook, the component doesn't mount for the first two stories and I get the following error in the console:

> [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <my-button> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.

I've tried the component both with and without the name, and variations of the name. I've attempted to add the component to each story, but that results in different errors.

I think there might be something wrong with how the file or how I've included typescript, because the styles/scss isn't loading for the component I don't get the error for either. But that's a bug for later...

MyButton.vue

```
<template>
  <button class="button-style" @click="onClick">
    <slot></slot>
  </button>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
  import { Vue, Component, Emit } from 'vue-property-decorator'

@Component({ name: 'MyButton' })
export default class MyButton extends Vue {

  @Emit('click')
  onClick(e){
    return e;
  }

}
</script>

<style lang="scss">
.button-style {
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  border-radius: 3;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 15;
  padding: 3px 10px;
  margin: 10;
}
</style>
```

MyButton.stories.tsx

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import { storiesOf } from '@storybook/vue';

import MyButton from './MyButton.vue';

storiesOf('MyButton', module)
  .add('with text', () => '<my-button>with text</my-button>')
  .add('with emoji', () => '<my-button>   </my-button>')
  .add('as a component', () => ({
    components: { 
        'my-button': MyButton 
    },
    template: '<my-button :rounded="true">rounded</my-button>',
    summary: 'Summary for MyButton'
  }));
```

webpack.config.ts

```
module.exports = ({ config }) => {
  config.module.rules.push({
    test: /\.(ts|tsx)$/,
    use: [
      {
        loader: require.resolve('ts-loader'),
        options: {
          appendTsSuffixTo: [/\.vue$/],
          transpileOnly: true
        }
      }
    ],
  });

  config.module.rules.push({
    test: /\.vue$/,
    loader: 'storybook-addon-vue-info/loader',
    enforce: 'post'
  });

  config.module.rules.push({
    test: /\.scss$/,
    use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader']
  });

  config.resolve.extensions.push('.ts', '.tsx', '.js');
  return config;
};
```